# Is there a way to split a string into an array with space(" ") separated values in ZSH?

Tags: zsh, variable-assignment

I have this code:

```
carp="2 hello 192.180.00.00"
array=( ${carp} )
echo "\n${array[2]}"
```

and I am trying to split carp into an array named array. my output should be "hello", but it just prints blank. Is there a simple way to split carp into an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

zsh has a [parameter expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html) syntax for that: `${=spec}`. To modify your example, it would be:

```
carp="2 hello 192.180.00.00"
array=( ${=carp} )
echo "\n${array[2]}"
```

The description is:

> Perform word splitting using the rules for SH_WORD_SPLIT during the evaluation of spec, but regardless of whether the parameter appears in double quotes; if the ‘=’ is doubled, turn it off. This forces parameter expansions to be split into separate words before substitution, using IFS as a delimiter. This is done by default in most other shells.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using the parameter flag `z`:

> ```
>   z      Split the result of the expansion into words using shell parsing to find the words, 
>          i.e. taking into account any quoting in the value.  Comments are not treated
>          specially but as ordinary strings, similar to interactive shells with the
>          INTERACTIVE_COMMENTS option unset (however, see the Z flag below for related options)
> ```

```
carp="2 hello 192.180.00.00"
array=( ${(z)carp} )
echo "\n${array[2]}"
```

or by specifying a custom split with `s`:

> ```
>    s:string:
>           Force field splitting at the separator string.  Note that a string of two or more characters means that all of them must match in sequence; this differs from the treatment of two or more
>           characters in the IFS parameter.  See also the = flag and the SH_WORD_SPLIT option.  An empty string may also be given in which case every character will be a separate element.
>
>           For historical reasons, the usual behaviour that empty array elements are retained inside double quotes is disabled for arrays generated by splitting; hence the following:
>
>                 line="one::three"
>                 print -l "${(s.:.)line}"
>
>           produces two lines of output for one and three and elides the empty field.  To override this behaviour, supply the ‘(@)' flag as well, i.e.  "${(@s.:.)line}".
> ```

```
carp="2 hello 192.180.00.00"
array=( ${(s/ /)carp} )
echo "\n${array[2]}"
```

You can also spare the creation of another variable like so:

```
carp="2 hello 192.180.00.00"
echo "\n${${(z)carp}[2]}"
```